# How to prevent Quartz.Net misfired job from retrying

Tags: quartz.net, misfire-instruction

I know I can specify *.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()* when building the trigger but some of my jobs are triggered via the *IScheduler.TriggerJob()* method, so without any triggers.

I can detect and log misfires in the *ITriggerListener* listener but how can I stop Quartz from trying to fire the job again? If I understand correctly *.VetoJobExecution* is not usable since the job has to be triggered successfully anyway.

Any other ideas?

Edit: my implementation

```
        JobDataMap jobData = new JobDataMap(data);
        IJobDetail jobTemplate = await jobScheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);


        var jobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .ForJob(jobTemplate)
            .UsingJobData(jobData)
            .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithRepeatCount(0).WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount())
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        await jobScheduler.ScheduleJob(jobTrigger);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you just want the `TriggerJob` behavior you can achieve that just by adding one simple trigger to scheduler that is going to trigger immediately and configure retry policy for that. So if you can change the call sites of `TriggerJob` to create a simple trigger instead (maybe an extension method that allows to define the policy), the Quartz source for TriggerJob [is here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/72ea693c4ad010b73d1c738f7c351a5a028864f6/src/Quartz/Core/QuartzScheduler.cs#L1005-L1032).

Comment: I've added my implementation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it.

You have to use the WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount policy, and WithRepeatCount(0).

But the trick here is to set the right value in the IScheduler MisfireThreshold to the misfire to be considered as a real misfire. I mean, if your misfire threshold is set to 60 seconds (default) then any job not executed in less than 60 seconds from schedule, will NOT be considered as a misfire. And so, the misfire policy will not be used.

In my case, with 3 second duration jobs, I had to set the WithMisfireThreshold to 1 second or less.

This way, the job is not retried if "really misfired".

Comment: I have write down a complete example on https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/1645